# Where is the code for copy and paste functionality located in Linux?

Tags: linux, operating-system

I'm just wondering where in the source files of a linux kernel I would be able to find the code which takes care of copying and pasting? I'm interested in modifying it but don't know where to look to find it.

Thanks

Comment: The lowest level of copy & paste is handled by X-Windows, not the kernel.

Comment: @Neil: depends on what you think is lowest level: I could argue that gpm is a lower level than X (besides, it's called *X* or the *X Window System*, not X-Windows, which is kind of a sobriquet).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Clipboard functionality is indeed not handled by the kernel but instead by the X window system and the active desktop manager (Gnome, KDE).

Take a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipboard_%28software%29#X_Window_System

> The usage and handling of various
>   selections is **not standardized**.
>   However most modern toolkits and
>   desktop environments, such as GNOME or
>   KDE, follow a widely accepted
>   convention, outlined in the
>   [freedesktop.org specification](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/ClipboardManager).

Comment: you might more properly say that it's handled by X _or_ the desktop manager.  AFAIK, the X and KDE clipboards are separate (the former accessible by highlight/middle-click, the latter by ctrl+x/ctrl+v)

Answer (score 2):

All you X addicts forget about the lovely console (and with that I don't mean terminal emulators like xterm and urxvt)! At the console, the copy-paste functionality is provided by [gpm](http://www.nico.schottelius.org/software/gpm/).

Comment: It would be useful if the questioner confirmed. Do people still run gpm? I recall it being around in old Red Hat days but notice there is no sign of it on my current systems.

Comment: @stsquad: I know several people running Linux who still use the console. In my distribution, installing gpm is as easy as `pacman -S gpm` and I guess it's equally easy on other distro's.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Linux handles copy paste. The kernel's function is to handle interaction between the hardware and the OS.

Usually that behavior(copy/paste) is part of the applications you may use.

Try looking in the source code for emacs or vi for examples.

Comment: how then you can copy from one app and past to another?

Comment: I think the confusion of Andrey (and indeed this entire question) is a by-product of the poor separation of concerns in MS Windows.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of thing is not handled by the kernel, but by the X windowing system and applications.

I suggest you read this wikipedia article on [X Window selection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection)